Unity Netcode - How to make nested Lists
I have some complex data structures with nested collections, that I would like to sync over the network. I initially though such a common problem would have a simple solution, but I have not been able to find any guidance on how to do this, Do anyone have an idea, or better an example of how to Sync complex datastructures, without having to use RPC's ?

First of all: do you really require a list of lists? Or would it be possible to rather have a fixed amount of lists so you can simply use multiple NetworkList fields? Otherwise you could probably create your own wrapper type using INetworkSerializable and implement your own synchronization for nested lists
